# Blazor Server App template not working on Visual Studio 2019 v 16.11.3

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, blazor

I have come to an issue while trying to create new project using Blazor template in Visual Studio 2019. After creating new Blazor project using template Blazor Server App I get an error at every line which includes '@' mark such as in _Host.cshtml file.

first line: @page "/".

> Error CS0103 The name 'page' does not exist in the current context.

I am using Visual Studio Community 2019 Version 16.11.3. In the link below there is a screenshot of this error. I have installed .NET SDK

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Sometimes there are ghost errors. Have you tried deleting obj and bin folder and doing a clean+rebuild?

Comment: Yes, no effect. I think i should also mention that whole template buillds successfully, alhtough it is reall inconvenient to work with whole text white and error marks. I have been trying to follow online tutorials step by step and install everything needed, but noone seems to have such problem as I do

Comment: Yeah. It happens many times. Delete .vs folder in your solution. It might get fixed upon restart.

Comment: Still does not work